# Issue in using nested array in angular2+

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

I am creating an application in angular2+ . Here i have created a nested array where we have a hierarchy as -
Organisation -> System -> Method -> Attribute.
The array is as follows -

```
completeArray  = [ "Organisation": 
    "EwayBill":[
        "Generate":

        {"Aadhar","Pan","DrivingLicense"}
    ], 
    "SMS", "Payments",
    "Collection":
    {"Aadhar", "VoterID"}
];
```

or

```
    Organisations = [

"System" : "EwayBill",
"Method" : ["Generate", "Update", "Cancel"],
"Attribute" : [
               "Generate":
               { "Aadhar","Pan","DrivingLicense" }]
]
```

As i researched, i came to know that in nested array, we have key-value pairs. But here i did not know how to create a key of the value, for example, "EwayBill","Collection" (which are Systems as defined in relationship mentioned above) that have values, are also values.

I want to correct my array.
 Also, suppose in the text box below -

[image]

i want to know how to find that aadhar is a value of Generate and Generate is a value of EwayBill as found out from the array.

Please help.

Comment: Arrays do not have keys in JS (just numeric indices). `{"Aadhar","Pan","DrivingLicense"}` looks invalid, so does most of that sample you posted. Did you post that as some kind of pseudo-code?

Comment: your `completeArray` dose not look like a valid json array

Comment: @Jeto , yes .. i kindof posted a puesdo code, and i want it corrected since i don't know the correct way of array. And i even don't know how to access them.

Comment: @Ebin. Can you help in writing a valid array

Comment: @Techdive I don't know what you are up to, but check this stakbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zukge2 I have inserted  valid json array in components, correct your question.

Comment: check this example https://model-based-angular-reactive-form-value-changes-with-rxw-jtwdye.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Ebin. I thank you. But, in the array --> EwayBill, SMS,Payments,Collections are all on the same level. No different / separate key for SMS,Payments

Comment: @Abhishek, your link doesn't open. Can you please check it again ?

Comment: Hi Mustapha, is my second mentioned array in question right ?

Comment: @Techdive try this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/model-based-angular-reactive-form-value-changes-with-rxw-u51mpx